# hibernate ServiceException caused by ClassLoadingException & ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, hibernate, servlets

I'm fairly new to using hibernate and I'm trying to create a webapp with hibernate as the backend but I'm running into an error I can't seem to figure out how to solve given the current configuration of my code. Any help would be appreciated

I have added my hibernate.cfg.xml configuration into the hibernateutil java class but i can't seem to get my configuration to read data from my database and keep getting
`org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]` 
caused by another error: `Caused by: org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.spi.ClassLoadingException: Unable to load class [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver]` and a `ClassNotFoundException` again to the mysql driver

i thought i configured my class properly but i can't seem to get it to work, here is my code where the error starts

```
public class HibernateUtil {
    private static SessionFactory sessionFactory;
    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        if (sessionFactory == null) {
            try {
                Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
                Properties settings = new Properties();
                
                // Hibernate settings equivalent to hibernate.cfg.xml's properties
                settings.put(Environment.DRIVER, "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                settings.put(Environment.URL, "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3308/demo");
                settings.put(Environment.USER, "user");
                settings.put(Environment.PASS, "password");
                settings.put(Environment.DIALECT, "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect");
                settings.put(Environment.SHOW_SQL, "true");
                settings.put(Environment.CURRENT_SESSION_CONTEXT_CLASS, "thread");
                settings.put(Environment.HBM2DDL_AUTO, "create-drop");
                configuration.setProperties(settings);
                configuration.addAnnotatedClass(Student.class);
                ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder()
                        .applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).build();
                
                sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return sessionFactory;
    }
}
```

here is my DAO class

```
public class StudentDAO {
    
    public void saveStudent(Student student) {
        Transaction transaction = null;
        try {
            Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
            transaction = session.beginTransaction();
            session.save(student);
            transaction.commit();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            if (transaction != null) {
                transaction.rollback();
            }
        }

    }
    
    public void updateStudent(Student student) {
        Transaction transaction = null;
        try {
            Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
            transaction = session.beginTransaction();
            session.saveOrUpdate(student); //student object updated
            transaction.commit();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            if (transaction != null) {
                transaction.rollback();
            }
        }

    }
    
    public Student getStudent(int id) {
        Transaction transaction = null;
        Student student = null;
        try {
            Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
            transaction = session.beginTransaction();
            student = session.get(Student.class, id); //get student object by id
            transaction.commit();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            if (transaction != null) {
                transaction.rollback();
            }
        }
        return student;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public List<Student> getAllStudents() {
        Transaction transaction = null;
        List<Student> students = null;
        try {
            Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
            transaction = session.beginTransaction();
            students = session.createQuery("from student").list(); //get all student objects
            transaction.commit();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            if (transaction != null) {
                transaction.rollback();
            }
        }
        return students;
    }
    
    @SuppressWarnings("null")
    public void deleteStudent(int id) {
        Transaction transaction = null;
        Student student = null;
        try {
            Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
            student = session.get(Student.class, id);
            if (student != null) {
                session.delete(student);
                System.out.println(student + "has been deleted");
            }
            transaction.commit();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            if (transaction != null) {
                transaction.rollback();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

and here is my servlet class

```
@WebServlet("/")
public class StudentServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2L;
    private StudentDAO studentDao;
    String home = "/Week05";

    public StudentServlet() {
        this.studentDao = new StudentDAO();
    }

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        doGet(request, response);
    }

    
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String sPath = request.getServletPath();
        //switch statement to call appropriate method
        switch (sPath) {
            case "/new":
                try {
                    showNewForm(request, response);
                } catch (ServletException | IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                break;
            case "/insert":
                try {
                    insertStudent(request, response);
                } catch (SQLException | IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } 
                break;
            case "/delete":
                try {
                    deleteStudent(request, response);
                } catch (SQLException | IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                break;
            case "/update":
                try {
                    updateStudent(request, response);
                } catch (SQLException | IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                break;
            case "/edit":
                try {
                    editStudent(request, response);
                } catch (ServletException | IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                break;
            default:
                try {
                    listAllStudents(request, response); //home page = .../week04/StudentServlet
                } catch (ServletException | IOException | SQLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } 
                break; 
            } 
    }

    // functions to fetch data from studentDao and display data on appropriate jsp
    private void listAllStudents(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) 
            throws ServletException, IOException, SQLException {
        List<Student> allStudents = studentDao.getAllStudents();
        request.setAttribute("listStudents", allStudents);
        RequestDispatcher dispatch = request.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp"); //home page week04/StudentServlet | list all objects from table
        dispatch.forward(request, response);
    }
    
    private void showNewForm(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) 
        throws ServletException, IOException {
        RequestDispatcher dispatch = request.getRequestDispatcher("student-form.jsp");
        dispatch.forward(request, response);
    }

    private void insertStudent(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) 
            throws SQLException, IOException{
        String firstname = request.getParameter("firstname");
        String lastname = request.getParameter("lastname");
        String email = request.getParameter("email");
        Student newStudent = new Student(firstname, lastname, email);
        studentDao.saveStudent(newStudent); //student object inserted to table 
        response.sendRedirect(home); //redirect to home page

    }
    
    private void deleteStudent(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) 
            throws SQLException, IOException {
        int id = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("id"));
        studentDao.deleteStudent(id); //student object deleted
        response.sendRedirect(home); 
    }
    
    private void updateStudent(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) 
            throws SQLException, IOException{
        int id = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("id"));
        String firstname = request.getParameter("firstname");
        String lastname = request.getParameter("lastname");
        String email = request.getParameter("email");
        Student updateStudent = new Student(id, firstname, lastname, email);
        studentDao.updateStudent(updateStudent); //student object updated
        response.sendRedirect(home);
    }
    
    private void editStudent(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) 
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        int id = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("id"));
//      String firstname = request.getParameter("firstname");
//      String lastname = request.getParameter("lastname");
//      String email = request.getParameter("email");
        Student currentStudent = studentDao.getStudent(id);
        RequestDispatcher dispatch = request.getRequestDispatcher("student-form.jsp"); //student form called with current student info loaded
        request.setAttribute("student", currentStudent); 
        dispatch.forward(request, response);
    }


}
```

Any help on where I'm going wrong would be appreciated as I truly can't figure what exactly  to do, it might be a mapping error issue but i assumed all necessary mapping was covered on the servlet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Alpheus
Your project can't find out your driver's dependency, because you haven't put dependency on build path.